# Printing sorted list c++

Tags: c++

I'm having a problem while printing sorted list. Every person have their mark. The list is sorted by descending marks, but when I try to print it only the place of marks has changed but names are left in their places like they were before sorting. How I can make it print correctly?

This is the sorting method:

```
void DynList::Sorting_name()
{
    list *R = P, *R1;
    string k;
    while (R != NULL) {
        R1 = R->next;
        while (R1 != NULL) {
            if (R1->name < R->name) {
                k = R->name;
                R->name = R1->name;
                R1->name = k;
            }
            R1 = R1->next;
        }
        R = R->next;
    }
}
```

and this is output method

```
void DynList::Output()
{
    list* D = P;
    int sk = 0;
    while (D) {
        sk++;
        cout << sk << ". " << D->name << " " << D->surname << " " << D->sk << endl;
        D = D->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: please include a [mcve]. Btw you seem to have `using namespace std;`, which is very bad in combination with using names from std such as `list`

Comment: what is your expected result as you said "correctly"?

Comment: your sorting only shuffles `name` and then you expect `surname` to be sorted as well?

Comment: Swap entire nodes, not single values. Manipulate pointers instead of strings to do so.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the following piece of code:

```
        if (R1->name < R->name) {
            k = R->name;
            R->name = R1->name;
            R1->name = k;
        }
```

Here you should be swapping either nodes or at least the whole contents of your nodes. If you want to swap your nodes, you'll have to store the predecessors of those nodes as well, while iterating over the list.

If `a` and `b` are the nodes, you want to swap and `ap`, `bp` are their predecessors, you want something like this:

```
swap(ap->next, bp->next);
swap(a->next, b->next);
```

If you want a solution for productive code, I'd consider using a suitable standard container and the respective sorting function, e.g. `std::list` and its `sort` member function or `std::deque` and the `std::sort` algorithm.